# Possible ways to split up and then recombine lecture notes

Tags: input, include, standalone, subfiles

I'm teaching Math Methods of Physics this fall, and want to provide written notes after class for the students to use.  I'd like for them to be individual lectures, but combinable into one document with page numbers and a table of contents. (I'm currently using the article class, sections, subsections and subsubsections.)  Naturally, I'll be using images, mathematical equations, arrays, and all that sweet LaTeX goodness.

I've read over the descriptions of how to use \input and \include, as well as the packages \standalone and \subfiles.  What's the cleanest way to get continuous page numbering and the ability to create a ToC from a bunch of individual files?  I'm still not sure of the relative strengths and weaknesses of these approaches.  Importantly, will the page numbers carry over from one lecture to the next?  If not, a ToC will be fairly useless.

My headers for an individual lecture (clearly needs editing to get to where I want to go):

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Mathematical Methods of Physics}                
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite,latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.25in}

\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }

\setul{4pt}{.4pt}
\newcommand{\tabletitle}[1]{\caption*{\ul{#1}}}
\newcommand{\<}{\:\!}
\newcommand{\bull}{\, \vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}} \,} % middle sized dot, between \cdot and \bullet, in math mode
\newcommand{\inv}{\:\!{\text -}1}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\dx}{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}}


\title{Mathematical Methods of Physics}
\author{Martin F. Melhus}
\date{\today}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}



Physics 309 covers the mathematical methods of physics.  The class meets on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, from 1:00 PM to 1:50 PM, in Kirkbride Hall, room xxx.  The instructor is Professor Martin Melhus.  Dr. Melhus's office is in Kirkbride Hall, room 246, and his campus phone extension is 4377.

\newpage

\section{Fundamentals}

We begin the course by examining the fundamental mathematical principles that we already know, ...
```

Additionally, I'd be happy to get any comments on better ways to do the stuff I'm doing (I thought I earned a Ph.D. in LaTeX when wrote the thesis for my actual Ph.D. in Physics, but it seems I still have much more to learn).

Comment: Please can you add one simple code or minimal code (minimal working example)?

Comment: Sebastiano, not sure how it will help, but the header for my first (so far only) set of notes is now included in the question.

Comment: I think that with your code you have received the answer. :-) Good work and good LaTeX.

Comment: Using [subfiles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) is certainly one way to go. For a similar use-case I wrote a small python script to automatically extract the pages for each lecture/week using hooks that I had LaTeX put in the aux file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using subfiles you can get correct page numbering by using the `zref-xr` package.

Assuming your main file is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{chap1}

\lipsum

\subfile{chap2}


\end{document}
```

and your subfile is called `chap2.tex`:

```
% !TeX root = chap2.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}


\IfEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{main}}{}{%
    \usepackage{zref-xr}
    \zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
    \zexternaldocument*[main-]{main}  
    \setcounterpageref{page}{main-chap2}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap2}
\label{chap2}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This will give you the whole document with a table of contents and a subdocument with the correct page numbering. You need to first compile the main document and then the subfile.

Comment: Samcarter, thanks.  This seems to work fine.  Playing with a few other page numbering commands, I was able to get the main body to start with page 1, and the table of contents to be indexed in roman numerals.  And the individual compilation of files also works fine.  Thanks a lot for the help, it's working great.

Comment: Found a small error - i was still using \setcounterpageref{page}{main-chap2} when my subdocument was called N01M.tex, and the page numbering was starting with 0 when I typeset the subfile.  I changed the argument to the proper filename, and now main won't compile, giving me a File ended while scanning use of \@xs@reserved@A.  I can post both headers in a new question if that would help.

Comment: @Martin replace `chap2` with the label of the chapter, not with the filename

Comment: Still doesn't work, same error.  Going to look into whether there's a package conflict.  Any other advice?  I didn't have labels before, added them in.  My format is an article, does that matter?

Comment: @Martin If you can make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I could take a look.

Comment: I'll do so, and repost as a separate question. Thanks.